# GetTemplateChild in Costum Control from CellTemplate of a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, custom-controls

I have a wpf c# customControl with the following DataGrid.
I would like to get the Border in the DataTemplate as I can do it with the DataGrid and the DataGridTemplateColumn in

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
     var dataGrid = GetTemplateChild("PART_DataGrid") as DataGrid;
     var tempColumn = GetTemplateChild("PART_TempColumn") as DataGridTemplateColumn;

}
```

Why does

```
var timerPointer = GetTemplateChild("PART_Border") as Border;
```

not work (always null) and how do I get the Border?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PART_DataGrid" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="PART_TempColumn" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="PART_Border" >
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Is Part_DataGrid inside ControlTemplate?

Comment: Yes it is inside of the style of the control template

Comment: Take a look at the answer I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why its not working is because you are searching in ControlTemplate scope but the element is defined in DataTemplate scope.

Here is an example how to make it run.

This is the ControlTemplate just like you have it.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button x:Name="bttn">
                            <Button.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" Text="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Button.ContentTemplate>
                        click me
                    </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

And this is the OnApplyTemplate method.

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
            new Action(
                () =>
                    {
                        var button = this.GetTemplateChild("bttn") as Button;
                        for (DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(button, 0);
                             child != null;)
                        {
                            if (child is ContentPresenter)
                            {
                                var parent = (ContentPresenter)child;
                                var element = parent.ContentTemplate.FindName("txtBlock", parent) as TextBlock;
                                if (element != null)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Found it!");
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(child) > 0)
                            {
                                child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(child, 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }));

        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
```

As you can see you first need to find the right scope and then you can search for the name of the element.